# How to configure gVIM with Mingw32?

Tags: c++, shell, vim, mingw32

I am trying to compile a c++ file.

How do you configure gVIM to make/compile files using `mingw32-make.exe`

I get a `shell returned 2` error and `No targets specified and no makefile found`
another thing i have noticed is that it's passing a `C:\..\LOCALS~1\TEMP\something.tmp 2>&1` folder to `mingw32-make.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the vim command line:

`:set makeprg=c:/path/to/mingw32-make.exe`

Once you have it working, put the set command in .vimrc

Edit:
Is there a file named `Makefile` in the current directory?
If not, create `Makefile` in the current directory and have it call your makefile.

For example, if you build your software with `mingw32-make project.mak` create `Makefile` with contents something like this:

```
all:
    mingw32-make project.mak
```

Comment: I did this already, I just noticed it gives me the same error in command prompt too :S

Comment: I have a makefile in a folder called release and is not in the same folder as my source files. This was a project made with another IDE but can't remember.